# How to acquire a token when it expires using MSAL in Vue 3 + composition api

Tags: typescript, vue.js, azure-ad-msal, quasar-framework

I used this repo on github https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/vue3-sample-app
I fallow the code examples Profie.vue and ProfileNoGuard.vue, so my problem is when the token expired, my spa can't make request to the api succesfully, i got 401 error, if I refresh the page F5 works fine, i need the help in order to write a cleaner code to call api resources for each function for example:

```
const fn1() => {
  if (result.value) {
  const graphData = await callMsGraph(endpoint1,result.value.accessToken).catch(() =>   acquireToken());
  state.data = graphData;
  state.resolved = true;
  }

const fn2() => {
  if (result.value) {
  const graphData = await callMsGraph(endpoint2,result.value.accessToken).catch(() =>   acquireToken());
  state.data = graphData;
  state.resolved = true;
  }
```

This fallow the pattern of ProfileNoguard.vue, then each time I need to call a function I need to check if result.value, and in the catch block call  acquireToken().

If a follow the pattern in Profile.vue then I need write the code below for each function that I will write

```
const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest
    }).catch(async (e) => {
        if (e instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            await instance.acquireTokenRedirect(loginRequest);
        }
        throw e;
    });
    if (inProgress.value === InteractionStatus.None) {
        const graphData = await callMsGraph(response.accessToken);
        state.data = graphData;
        state.resolved = true;
        stopWatcher();
    }
```

I saw another post at https://dev.to/425show/secure-your-vue-js-apis-with-azure-ad-b2c-42j6
in which define a service

```
class DaveCoApi {
    async getSuperSecretThings(): Promise<any[]> {
        const accessToken = await msalPluginInstance.acquireToken();
        const response = await fetch('/api/secret/', {
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });
        if (response.ok){
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
export default new DaveCoApi();
```

So basically I need something like acquire the right token, taking into account if expired and place it in just one place the logic, for reuse this code everywhere

I attached below on componet that I used and I know have bad practices every time I call the web api

```
<template>
  <div class="header-index row items-center justify-evenly">
    <h5
      class="text-white"
      style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"
    >
      Lista de Eventos
    </h5>
    <!-- <q-badge color="secondary" multi-line>
        Model: "{{ model }}"
      </q-badge> -->
  </div>
  <div class="q-pa-md row items-center justify-center q-gutter-md">
    <q-select
      clearable
      v-model="model"
      :options="units"
      label="Unidade"
      style="width: 350px"
      @update:model-value="changeUnit"
      ref="unitSel"
    />

    <q-input v-model="date" style="width: 350px" label="Data do Evento" ref="dateInp">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
            <q-date
              v-model="date"
              mask="DD-MM-YYYY"
              :locale="ptLocale"
              @update:model-value="changeDate"
            >
              <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                <q-btn v-close-popup label="Fechar" color="primary" flat />
              </div>
            </q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
  <div class="row row items-center justify-center q-gutter-xl">
    <p><q-icon name="square" color="positive" /> Aprovado</p>
    <p><q-icon name="square" color="warning" /> Pendente</p>
    <p><q-icon name="square" color="negative" /> Reprovado</p>
  </div>

  <div class="q-ml-xl row items-start q-gutter-xl">
    <q-card
      class="my-card"
      :class="
        event.status === EventStatus.Pendent
          ? 'warningBor'
          : event.status === EventStatus.Approved
          ? 'positiveBor'
          : 'negativeBor'
      "
      v-for="event in events"
      :key="event.id"
    >
      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn
          :to="'/cadastro-evento-preenchido/' + event.id"
          flat
          round
          color="blue-grey-13"
          icon="visibility"
        />
        <q-btn
          :to="'/editar-evento/' + event.id"
          flat
          round
          :color="
            event.status === EventStatus.Pendent
              ? 'warning'
              : event.status === EventStatus.Approved
              ? 'positive'
              : 'negative'
          "
          icon="edit"
          :disable="event.status !== EventStatus.Pendent"
        />
        <q-btn
          flat
          round
          color="grey"
          icon="close"
          @click="showRejectEvt(event.id)"
          :disable="userRol.includes(Role.Connections)"
        />
      </q-card-actions>

      <q-card-section>
        <div
          class="text-h6 q-mb-xs"
          :class="
            event.status === EventStatus.Pendent
              ? 'text-warning'
              : event.status === EventStatus.Approved
              ? 'text-positive'
              : 'text-negative'
          "
        >
          {{ event.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="row no-wrap items-center">
          <q-item-label caption>{{ event.startDate }}</q-item-label>
        </div>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions>
        <q-btn
          no-caps
          flat
          :class="{ 'text-negative': event.status === EventStatus.Rejected }"
          :disable="event.status !== EventStatus.Pendent"
          @click="showFiles(event.id)"
          >Arquivos</q-btn
        >
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </div>
  <q-dialog v-if="showDialogTest" v-model="confirm" persistent>
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section class="row items-center">
        <q-avatar icon="error" color="negative" text-color="white" />
        <span class="q-ml-sm">Deseja realmente rejeitar este evento?</span>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn
          flat
          no-caps
          label="Sim"
          color="positive"
          v-close-popup
          @click="rejectEvent"
        />
        <q-btn flat no-caps label="Não" color="negative" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>

  <q-dialog v-if="showDialogTest" v-model="confirmAprbarEvt" persistent>
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section class="row items-center">
        <q-avatar icon="error" color="negative" text-color="white" />
        <span class="q-ml-sm">Deseja realmente aprovar este evento?</span>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn
          no-caps
          flat
          label="Sim"
          color="positive"
          v-close-popup
          @click="aprobarEvt"
        />
        <q-btn flat no-caps label="Não" color="negative" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
  <!--Aprobar arquivo -->
  <q-dialog v-if="showDialogTest" v-model="confirmAprobarFile" persistent>
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section class="row items-center">
        <q-avatar icon="error" color="negative" text-color="white" />
        <span class="q-ml-sm">Deseja realmente aprovar este arquivo?</span>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn
          no-caps
          flat
          label="Sim"
          color="positive"
          v-close-popup
          @click="aprobarArquivo"
        />
        <q-btn no-caps flat label="Não" color="negative" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>

  <!-- Rechazar arquvio -->
  <q-dialog v-if="showDialogTest" v-model="confirmRechazarFile" persistent>
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section class="row items-center">
        <q-avatar icon="error" color="negative" text-color="white" />
        <span class="q-ml-sm"
          >Se você realmente deseja rejeitar este arquivo, insira o motivo</span
        >
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-section class="q-pt-none">
        <div class="q-pa-md">
          <q-option-group :options="options" type="radio" v-model="group" ref="optionRejectFile"/>
          <q-input v-show="group == '6'"  dense v-model="reason" autofocus />
          <!--  -->
        </div>

      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn
          no-caps
          flat
          label="Sim"
          color="positive"
          @click="rechazarArquivo"
        />
        <q-btn no-caps flat label="Não" color="negative" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>

  <!-- dialog with files asociated to the event -->
  <q-dialog v-if="showDialogTest" v-model="showFileDialog">
    <q-card style="width: 800px; max-width: 80vw">
      <q-card-section>
        <div class="text-h6">Arquivos</div>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-section class="q-pt-none">
        <div v-show="!isFileShowed">
          <div
            class="row"
            v-for="docEvt in docEvts"
            :key="docEvt.category"
            style="margin-bottom: 25px"
          >
            <div
              v-if="docEvt.category != '0' || docEvt.docId != null"
              class="col-7"
            >
              <q-btn

                no-caps
                class="csWidth"
                :label="docEvt.label"
                filled
                rounded
                :color="
                  docEvt.status == null
                    ? 'primary'
                    : docEvt.status === ArchiveStatus.Approved
                    ? 'positive'
                    : 'negative'
                "
              />
            </div>
            <div
              v-if="docEvt.category != '0' || docEvt.docId != null"
              class="col-5 row items-center q-gutter-md"
            >
              <q-btn
                icon="description"
                no-caps
                flat
                rounded
                :color="docEvt.color"
                :disable="docEvt.color == 'grey'"
                @click="showFileArea(true, docEvt.src, docEvt.rejectionReason)"
              ></q-btn>
              <q-btn
                v-if="!docEvt.disabled && userRol.includes(Role.Juridico)"
                icon="thumb_up"
                no-caps
                size="sm"
                rounded
                color="positive"
                @click="showAprobarFile(docEvt.docId)"
              ></q-btn>
              <q-btn
                v-if="!docEvt.disabled && userRol.includes(Role.Juridico)"
                icon="thumb_down"
                no-caps
                size="sm"
                rounded
                color="negative"
                @click="showRechazarFile(docEvt.docId)"
              ></q-btn>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-show="isFileShowed">
          <q-btn
            flat
            color="primary"
            @click="showFileArea(false)"
            icon="close"
          />

          <iframe
            :src="srcFile"
            allow="fullscreen"
            width="800"
            height="700"
          ></iframe>
          <p
            v-if="rejectionReason != null && rejectionReason != ''"
            class="text-negative"
          >
            Arquivo rejeitado: {{ rejectionReason }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions v-show="!isFileShowed" align="center">
        <q-btn
          no-caps
          label="Aprovar evento"
          flat
          color="primary"
          @click="confirmAprbarEvt = true"
          :disable="! userRol.includes(Role.Juridico)"
        />
        <q-btn no-caps label="Fechar" flat color="primary" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>

  <br />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  Event,
  Select,
  DocEvt,
  ApiResp,
  DropDownInfo,
} from 'components/models';
import { computed, defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { api, baseUrl } from 'boot/axios';
import { ptLocale, showAlert } from 'boot/util';

import { callGetApi } from 'src/utils/MsGraphApiCall';
import { useMsalAuthentication } from 'src/composition-api/useMsalAuthentication';
import { InteractionType } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { loginRequest } from 'src/authConfig';
import { ArchiveStatus, EventStatus, Role } from 'components/enums';
import { useMsal } from 'src/composition-api/useMsal';
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'


export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  components: {
    /*ExampleComponent*/
  },
  props: {
    showDialogTest: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const { result, acquireToken } = useMsalAuthentication(
      InteractionType.Redirect,
      loginRequest
    );
    const router = useRouter();
    const { accounts } = useMsal();

    const units = ref<Select[]>();
    const msg = ref<string>('');
    const model = ref<Select>();
    const date = ref('');
    const unitId = ref(-1);
    const events = ref<Event[]>();
    const selectedEvt = ref(-1);
    const confirm = ref(false);
    const docEvts = ref<DocEvt[]>();
    const showFileDialog = ref(false);
    const srcFile = ref('https://url.com');
    const isFileShowed = ref(false); //para mostrar ocultar area archivos
    const confirmAprobarFile = ref(false);
    const confirmRechazarFile = ref(false);
    const currDocId = ref(0); //id del archivo seleccionado para aprobar o rechazar
    const currEvtId = ref(0);
    const reason = ref(''); //razon de rejeitar archivo
    const confirmAprbarEvt = ref(false);
    const showAprobarEvt = ref(false);
    const rejectionReason = ref(''); //si un archivo es desaprobado mostrar la razon;
    const group = ref(null);
    const options = [
        { label: 'O documento apresentado é um protocolo, não o documento final expedido pelo órgão público', value: '1' },
        { label: 'O documento apresentado é um rascunho, não o documento definitivo expedido pelo órgão público', value: '2' },
        { label: 'O documento apresentado é divergente do documento solicitado', value: '3' },
        { label: 'O contrato apresentado não está assinado pelas partes', value: '4' },
        { label: 'O documento apresentado não se refere ao evento cadastrado', value: '5' },
        { label: 'Outro comentário', value: '6' }
      ];

    async function rejectEvent() {
      try {
        if (!result.value) return;
        const apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          `api/Event/RejectEvent/${selectedEvt.value}`
        );

        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;
        //await api.get<ApiResp>(`api/Event/RejectEvent/${selectedEvt.value}`);
        await loadEvents();
      } catch (err: any) {
        showAlert(
          `Não foi possível rejeitar este evento: ${
            err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err
          }`
        );
      }
    }

    const showRejectEvt = (evtId: number) => {
      //console.log("show",evtId);
      confirm.value = true;
      selectedEvt.value = evtId;
      //console.log('sel', evtId);
    };

    async function loadUnits(apiResult: any) {
      try {
        //const resp = await api.get('/api/Enum/GetUnitsDropdownItems');
        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;
        units.value = apiResult.data.result.map((o: DropDownInfo) => {
          return { label: o.text, value: parseInt(o.value) };
        });
        //if (units.value != undefined) model.value = units.value[0];
      } catch (err: any) {
        showAlert(
          `Falha ao carregar unidades: ${
            err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err
          }`
        );
      }
    }
    async function loadEvents() {
      try {
        /*
        const resp = await api.get(
          'api/Event/GetPaginatedList?Unit=' +
            unitId.value +
            '&SkipCount=0&Date=' +
            date.value
        );*/
        if (!result.value) return;
        const unitTemp = unitId.value < 0 ? '' : unitId.value;
        const apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          'api/Event/GetPaginatedList?Unit=' +
            unitTemp +
            '&SkipCount=0&Date=' +
            date.value
        );

        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;
        events.value = apiResult.data.result.items;
      } catch (err: any) {
        showAlert(
          `Falha ao carregar eventos: ${err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err}`
        );
      }
    }

    const changeUnit = async (val: Select) => {
      //console.log("change unit",val.label);
      unitId.value = val ? val.value : -1;
      await loadEvents();
    };

    const changeDate = async (value: any, reason: any, details: any) => {
      //console.log("Date",value);
      date.value = value;
      await loadEvents();
    };

    const fillDocEvt = () => {
      docEvts.value = [];
      const labels = [
        'Alvará do evento',
        'Auto de Vistoria do Corpo de Bombeiros (AVCB)',
        'Contrato de Bombeiros Civis',
        'Contrato de UTI Móvel',
        'Contrato de Segurança Privada',
        'Contrato de Patrocínio Assinado Pelas Partes',
        'Autorização da Área de compliance',
      ];
      for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        let cat = i === 1 ? '1' : '' + (i + 1);
        if (i === 7) cat = '0';

        docEvts.value?.push({
          color: 'grey',
          disabled: true,
          src: '',
          file: new File([], ''),
          category: cat,
          label: labels[i - 1],
          docId: null,
          status: null,
          rejectionReason: null,
        });
      }
      //console.log("evtDoc", docEvts.value);
    };

    const aprobarEvt = async () => {
      try {
        if (!result.value) return;
        const apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          `/api/Event/ApproveEvent/${currEvtId.value}`
        );
        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;
        //await api.get(`/api/Event/ApproveEvent/${currEvtId.value}`);
        await loadEvents();
        showFileDialog.value = false; // close dialog
        msg.value = 'Evento aprovado com sucesso';
        showAlert(msg.value, true);
      } catch (err: any) {
        msg.value = err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err
        showAlert(
          `Não foi possível aprovar este evento: ${msg.value}`
        );
      }
    };

    const showFiles = async (evtId: number) => {
      fillDocEvt(); //clear status
      currEvtId.value = evtId;
      try {
        if (!result.value) return;
        const apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          `/api/Archive/GetUploadedArchives?eventId=${evtId}`
        );

        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;
        //console.log('Hola');
        /* const resp = await api.get(
          `/api/Archive/GetUploadedArchives?eventId=${evtId}`
        ); */
        apiResult.data.forEach(
          (x: {
            id: number;
            category: string;
            status: number | null;
            rejectionReason: string | null;
          }) => {
            const evt = docEvts.value?.filter((e) => e.category == x.category);
            //buscar cada evento existente y llenarlo de acuerdo a info de la api
            if (evt != undefined && evt?.length > 0) {
              const first = evt[0];
              first.docId = x.id;
              first.status = x.status;
              first.color = x.id ? 'orange' : 'grey';
              first.disabled = x.status != null;
              first.src = baseUrl + '/api/Archive/Show/' + x.id;
              first.rejectionReason = x.rejectionReason;
            }
          }
        );
        showFileDialog.value = true;
      } catch (err: any) {
        showAlert(
          `Falha ao carregar arquivos: ${
            err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err
          }`
        );
      }
    };

    const showFileArea = (flag: boolean, src = '', _rejectionReason: '') => {
      isFileShowed.value = flag;
      srcFile.value = src;
      rejectionReason.value = _rejectionReason;
      //console.log("src", src);
    };

    const aprobarArquivo = async () => {
      try {
        if (!result.value) return;
        const apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          `/api/Archive/ApproveArchive/${currDocId.value}`
        );

        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;

        // const resp = await api.get(
        //   `/api/Archive/ApproveArchive/${currDocId.value}`
        // );
        await showFiles(currEvtId.value);
      } catch (err: any) {
        showAlert(
          `Não foi possível aprovar este arquivo: ${
            err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err
          }`
        );
      }
    };
    const rechazarArquivo = async () => {
      //console.log("group",group.value);
      if (group.value == null || group.value == '6' && reason.value.trim().length === 0) {
        showAlert('Insira o motivo');
        return;
      }
      try {
        if (!result.value) return;
        let comment = options[group.value-1].label;
        if(group.value == '6')
          comment += `: ${reason.value}`;
        const apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          `/api/Archive/RejectArchive?ArchiveId=${currDocId.value}&RejectionReason=${comment}`
        );

        if (!apiResult.data) throw apiResult;
        // const resp = await api.get(
        //   `/api/Archive/RejectArchive?ArchiveId=${currDocId.value}&RejectionReason=${reason.value}`
        // );
        await showFiles(currEvtId.value);
        reason.value = '';
        confirmRechazarFile.value = false;
      } catch (err: any) {
        showAlert(
          `Não foi possível rejeitar este arquivo: ${
            err.response?.data.errorMessage ?? err
          }`
        );
      }
    };
    const showRechazarFile = (docId: number) => {
      confirmRechazarFile.value = true; // propmt for reason
      currDocId.value = docId;
    };
    const showAprobarFile = (docId: number) => {
      confirmAprobarFile.value = true;
      currDocId.value = docId;
      //console.log("currDocId",docId);
    };
    onMounted(async () => {
      fillDocEvt();
      //await loadUnits();
      //await loadEvents();
    });

    async function updateData() {
      if (result.value != undefined && result.value.accessToken) {
        let apiResult = await callGetApi(
          result.value.accessToken,
          '/api/Enum/GetUnitsDropdownItems'
        ).catch(() => acquireToken());
        await loadUnits(apiResult);
        /*apiResult = await callGetApi(result.value.accessToken, 'api/Event/GetPaginatedList?Unit=' +
            unitId.value +
            '&SkipCount=0&Date=' +
            date.value).catch(() =>
          acquireToken()
        );*/
        await loadEvents();
      }
    }

    const testRouterDetails = () => router.push(`/cadastro-evento-preenchido/40`)
    const testRouterEdit = () => router.push(`/editar-evento/40`)

    updateData();

    watch(result, () => {
      // Fetch new data from the API each time the result changes (i.e. a new access token was acquired)
      updateData();
    });

    const userRol = computed(() => {
      //console.log("user rol" , userRol);
      if (accounts.value.length > 0) {
        return accounts.value[0].idTokenClaims?.preferred_username; //fixRole
      }
      return '';
    });

    return {
      docEvts,
      units,
      model,
      events,

      date,
      ptLocale,
      changeUnit,
      changeDate,
      confirm,
      showRejectEvt,
      rejectEvent,
      showFileDialog,
      showAprobarEvt,
      confirmAprbarEvt,
      aprobarEvt,
      showFiles,
      showFileArea,
      isFileShowed,
      srcFile,
      confirmAprobarFile,
      confirmRechazarFile,
      aprobarArquivo,
      rechazarArquivo,
      showAprobarFile,
      showRechazarFile,
      reason,
      baseUrl,
      EventStatus,
      ArchiveStatus,
      rejectionReason,
      group,
      userRol,
      Role,
      options,
      testRouterDetails,
      testRouterEdit,
      msg,
      currEvtId,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```